# Unable to switch focus to child window in Safari browser using Protractor

Tags: javascript, safari, protractor

Unable to switch focus to Child window in Safari browser version 11 and 12

OS version : macOS High Sierra and macOS Mojave

Below is the code snippet that I have tried.

```
exports.switchWindowFocus = function (url) {

    var self = this;

     browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {

        browser.wait(self.windowCount(2), 10000);

         browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function(){

             expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(url);
         })
    });
};
```

Still the focus remains on the main window instead of switching to child window.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to see the `browser.wait(self.windowCount(2))` inside the `browser.getAllWindowHandles()`.  If you get all the handles and it wasn't there yet, then waiting for it afterwards won't do much good.  Also, the `browser.wait` should probably be promise chained with whatever comes after.  Maybe something like (untested):

```
exports.switchWindowFocus = function (url) {
  var self = this;
  browser.wait(self.windowCount(2), 10000).then(function() {
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
      console.log(handles.length);
      browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function() {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(url);
      })
    });
  });
};
```